# Http PATCH request for Titanium

Tags: android, http, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

How to use PATCH method for Http request in Titanium? It is not supported method in Android.

In past I could download tiokhttp module but it is obsolete and is not working with new SDK versions.

I have code build over Titanium's HTTPClient so it would be best if modification would require no big changes in structure of HTTPClient declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried myself, but are you sure PATCH doesn't work? According to Appcelerator's documentation, it is supported since release 4.1.0:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/HTTPClient_and_the_Request_Lifecycle-section-src-29004904_HTTPClientandtheRequestLifecycle-Contents

Comment: PATCH method is not working on Android as it is explained here:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19564.
I get following error if I try to use PATCH method:  Unknown method 'PATCH'; must be one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE]